# Using results of one query into the next with unlike column names

Tags: mysql, sql

My Platform is **MySql**

I have two queries that I need to combine, using the first query as a type of filter for the second query.

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM INVENTORY
WHERE INV_ID = 1
AND FSCL_YR = 2017
```

From this query we will get results back that includes a column named `STR_NBR`.

Which we then want to use in the second query as 'If the store number appears in the first query, give me the results where it shows in the second'. The second query tables use the column name `SND_LOC_NBR` instead of `STR_NBR`.

Query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM Transfer A
LEFT JOIN Transfer_Detail B
ON A.XFER_NBR = B.XFER_NBR
WHERE A.XFER_NBR = B.XFER_NBR
AND A.XFER_STAT_IND IN ('S','C')
AND (where the SND_LOC_NBR needs to match STR_NBRs found from Query 1)
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far and where are you finding it does not work?

Comment: While this might not fix your problem (I haven't read your question yet) it is worth noting that the first `WHERE` clause on your second query eliminating `NULL` values (you don't even need this condition - you already have it in the `ON` clause of your `LEFT JOIN`), thus transforming your `OUTER JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Transfer A
      LEFT JOIN Transfer_Detail B
         ON A.XFER_NBR = B.XFER_NBR
      WHERE A.XFER_STAT_IND IN ('S','C')
        AND SND_LOC_NBR IN 
              (SELECT STR_NBR FROM INVENTORY 
                   WHERE INV_ID = 1 AND FSCL_YR = 2017 )
```